# d3/js data manipulation dropping columns

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a dataset in csv and it looks like below.

```
country,col1,col2,col3
Germany,19979188,11233906,43.7719591
UK,3839766,1884423,50.92349378
France,1363608,796271,41.60557873
Italy,957516,557967,41.72765781
```

I'd like to drop col1, col2 off while keeping country and col3. If possible, I'd like to wrap it into a function where I can pass column list that I'd like to drop/keep.

Using pandas, which I'm familiar with, I can easily do it. e.g. data.drop(['col1', 'col2'], axis = 1). But I found d3 way or js way in general is based on each row so couldn't come up with an idea to drop columns.

I was thinking of d3.map() taking desirable columns only. But I was stuck to build a general function that the column list can be passed in.

Could anyone have thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3 fetch methods, like `d3.csv`, will retrieve the **whole** CSV and will create an array of objects based on that CSV. Because of that, filtering out some columns is useless. Actually, it's worse than useless: you'll spend time and resources with an unnecessary operation.

Therefore, the only useful solution is, if you have access and own that CSV, creating a new CSV without those columns. That way you'll have a smaller file, faster to load. Otherwise, if you cannot change the CSV itself, don't bother: just load the whole thing and use the columns you want (which will be properties in the objects), ignoring the others.

Finally, if you have a lot of data manipulation it might be interesting reducing the size of the objects in the data array. If that's your case, use a **row function** to return only the properties you want. For instance:

```
d3.csv(url, function (d){
    return {country: d.country, col3: d.col3}
}).then(etc...)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's not what I expected but it prompts me to design the work better in the way of d3.